# SQL select query to get total unique entries from two foreign key tables based on a column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got three tables as shown below - ideally it wouldn't be laid out like this but currently no power change it.

```
Team              User                          Member

ID | Name         ID | TeamId | Email            ID | TeamId | Email
----------
1  | Team A       1  |  1     | a@email.com      1  |  1     | a@email.com
2  | Team B       2  |  1     | b@email.com      2  |  1     | b@email.com
3  | Team C                                      3  |  1     | c@email.com
```

I need to be able to get the combined count of users and members in each team, uniquely based on their email address.
So for example, Team A would have a unique count of combined members and users of 3.

An entry may exist in either the user table OR the member table, or in both for each email.
The outcome of the query would be TeamName and TotalUsers.

Any help with this type of query would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us your code ?

Comment: Sorry for not replying, I think both yours and Nbk's answers did the trick and only selected theirs due to posting prior.
However after looking into both answers, I think yours is slightly better due to grouping by ID and not name and also unecessary distinct, both gave me the answer I was looking for though, so thanks!

Comment: prior? Did you check the timestamps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNION` to collect all the distinct combinations of team ids and emails from `User` and `Member` and do  a `LEFT` join of `Team` to that resultset and aggregate:

```
SELECT t.id, t.name,
       COUNT(email) count
FROM Team t
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT teamid, email FROM User
  UNION
  SELECT teamid, email FROM Member
) e ON e.teamid = t.id
GROUP BY t.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can `UNION` members and User table, so that duplicates would be removed

And then join it to the temas table

```
SELECT 
   t1.Name, COUNT(DISTINCT Email)
FROM 
   Team  t1
   JOIN
   ( SELECT TeamId , Email FROM User
   UNION SELECT TeamId , Email FROM Member) t2 ON t2.TeamId = t1.ID
GROUP BY t1.Name
```

Comment: *UNION...so that duplicates would be removed* then why do you use DISTINCT?

Comment: @torpas i thought about it, but in end effect it doesn't matter, if i used it or not.